# android: loading html data with &nbsp in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

if data is loaded with

```
loadData(sBody, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

then  all the  newlines are removed. So the data comes with no  newline ie with no line seperators.

I tried

```
.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(sBody, "utf-8")
                            .replaceAll("\\+", "%20"), "text/plain", "utf-8");
```

then wherever there is newline i can see a space. Also someother unreadable characters coming

how can i fix this problem

The content is the body of email.
A sample email data given below

```html
Testing bug
&nbsp;
Test
&nbsp;
Test gaian 
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
```

the corresponding mail text is
testing bug (enter pressed )
test(enter pressed )
test gaian(2enter pressed )

Comment: Keep your text type as it is `text/html` only then check.

Comment: thats what i tried first with loadData(sBody, "text/html", "utf-8");  thank you

Comment: posting your html data will help to recognize problem..

Comment: please post your sBody data

Comment: The content is the body of email.A sample email data given below
Testing bug
&nbsp;
Test
&nbsp;
Test gaian 
&nbsp;
&nbsp;

Comment: i have added data in the question for more clarity